# ¿Se pueden combinar las rutas de archivo yml con annotations en symfony?

Tags: symfony, annotation, yml

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto que está empezado, y en el momento que se empezó se aconsejaba y se utilizaba un archivo de configuración `.yml` para las rutas, sin embargo hoy en día es más facil, usando las `annotations`

Mi pregunta es si hay algun amanera de combinar los dos tipos de rutas, ya que trabajar con archivos `.yml` es bastante tedioso, además el proyecto será migrado al nuevo sistema de `annotations` así que no tiene sentido añadir más rutas al archivo de configuración...

Yo lo he intentado y me ha salido el siguiente error:

> Whoops, looks like something went wrong.
>   [Syntax Error] Expected Doctrine\Common\Annotations\DocLexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS, got 'name' at position 122 in method AppBundle\Controller\Clientes\FichaController::bajaServicios() in /vagrant/www/intranet/src/AppBundle/Controller/ (which is being imported from "/vagrant/www/intranet/app/config/routing.yml"). Make sure annotations are enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si que se puede trabajar con los dos, revisa que tengas instalado y activado el `SensioFrameworkExtraBundle` primero que nada, este es el encargado de dar la flexibilidad de las anotaciones.

Revisa este documento oficial donde explica como se hace la importación de los archivos en diferentes formatos:

https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/routing/external_resources.html

(He puesto esta versión porque nunca dices cual usas.)

Recuerda que puedes llegar a sobre escribir rutas si no tienes cuidado.

saludos,